# How to increase wingpanel icon size

Tags: wingpanel, themes, hidpi

I have a 15.6 inch display, which has default resolution of 1920x1080, and the wingpanel indicator icons looks a bit small to me.

This is a known issue for displays that have a non-standard DPI value, but at least I have an option to scale the text, but the icons still looks very small and hard to read.

I've tied different icon themes like Arc and it fixed the issue, but I don't want to use non-standard themes because most of them lack some icons, and that creates a bad user experience.

Is there a way to increase wingpanel icons in the default elementary icon theme?